# Newbie in TypesSript - How to check an interface by an index

Tags: typescript

I have a list of operations to a DB and every one of them have a different set of variables which need to be passed on, I figured it would be much easier to add new operations if I set the interfaces inside a list, like this, where if there is a match the function would require the correct interface for that operation:

```
const operation = {
    add: 'example',
    list: 'example2',
};
```

```
interface operationVariable {
    add: { asset: string };
}
```

I'm trying to get the correct interface for each operation from a list like this:

```
function graphql<OP = keyof typeof operation>(request: OP, variables: operationVariable[OP], server = CONFIG.GRAPHQLSERVER) {
    return post(server, request);
}
```

An error message comes up:

> Type 'OP' cannot be used to index type 'operationVariable'.

Even if I remove the 'list' operation the error still persists...

How do I tell TypeScript to behave the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell TypeScript that `operation` is a record that uses keys of `operationVariable` and holds strings:

```
const operation: Record<keyof operationVariable, string> = {
    add: 'example',
    list: 'example2', // error, not in operationVariable
};
```

Then the part you were missing is `extends`. The `extends` keyword is a generic constraint that you can use to tell TypeScript that this generic type must be a subtype of another type:

```
function graphql<
    OP extends keyof typeof operation
//     ^^^^^^^ OP is a keyof typeof operation
>(request: OP, variables: operationVariable[OP], // works
```

Here's how the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) explains it.